# How to read ini file in spring batch (key=value)

Tags: java, spring, file, spring-batch, ini

I want to create a batch using Spring batch to read from an ini file and save the data in database but when I chekced the `org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader` class I didn't find a way to parse my data from the ini file , I tried to combine the `ini4j` API with the spring batch but no result

my ini file :

```
 [Cat]
    a=1
    b= 2
    c= 3
    d= 4
    e= 5
    f= 6
    [Cat2]
     a=11
    b= 21
    c= 31
    d= 41
    e= 51
    f= 61
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is define your own `ItemStreamReader` that wraps a delegate `ItemStreamReader`, which is just a `FlatFileItemReader` that uses a `PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper` as the line mapper. In your `ItemStreamReader`, loop to read lines from your delegate and if the line is an instance of a `Property` domain object then add it to a list in a `Section` domain object. What the `PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper` allows you do do is check the line for a pattern match, and pass it to the right tokenizer and fieldSetMapper for the job.

Doing it this way will allow you to read multiple lines into one `Section` domain object that holds a `List<Property>`.

```
public class Section {

    private String name;
    private List<Property> properties;
    // getters and setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(name);
        for (Property prop: properties) {
            sb.append("," + prop.getKey() + "=" + prop.getValue());
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}

public class Property {

    private String key;
    private String value;
    // getters and setters
}
```

For you custom `ItemStreamReader` you would do this. You can see that the reading is delegated to another reader, which you will define later

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ExecutionContext;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.NonTransientResourceException;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ParseException;
import org.springframework.batch.item.UnexpectedInputException;

public class IniFileItemReader implements ItemStreamReader<Object> {

    private Object curItem = null;
    private ItemStreamReader<Object> delegate;

    @Override
    public Object read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException,
            ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
        if (curItem == null) {
            curItem = (Section) delegate.read();
        }

        Section section = (Section) curItem;
        curItem = null;

        if (section != null) {
            section.setProperties(new ArrayList<Property>());

            while (peek() instanceof Property) {
                section.getProperties().add((Property) curItem);
                curItem = null;
            }
        }
        return section;
    }

    private Object peek() throws Exception {
        if (curItem == null) {
            curItem = delegate.read();
        }
        return curItem;
    }

    public void setDelegate(ItemStreamReader<Object> delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws ItemStreamException {
        delegate.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void open(ExecutionContext arg0) throws ItemStreamException {
        delegate.open(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(ExecutionContext arg0) throws ItemStreamException {
        delegate.update(arg0);
    }
}
```

Then in your config you define the deleagte reader with the `PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper`

```
<bean id="inputFile" class="org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource"
    scope="step">
    <constructor-arg value="#{jobParameters[inputFile]}"></constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="sectionFileReader"
    class="com.underdogdevs.springbatch.reader.IniFileItemReader">
    <property name="delegate" ref="trueSectionFileReader"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="trueSectionFileReader"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
    <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper">
            <property name="tokenizers">
                <map>
                    <entry key="[*" value-ref="sectionLineTokenizer">
                    </entry>
                    <entry key="*" value-ref="propertyLineTokenizer"></entry>
                </map>
            </property>
            <property name="fieldSetMappers">
                <map>
                    <entry key="[*" value-ref="sectionFieldSetMapper">
                    </entry>
                    <entry key="*" value-ref="propertyFieldSetMapper">
                    </entry>
                </map>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="resource" ref="inputFile"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="sectionLineTokenizer"
    class="com.underdogdevs.springbatch.tokenizer.SectionLineTokenizer">
</bean>

<bean id="sectionFieldSetMapper"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper">
    <property name="prototypeBeanName" value="section"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="section" class="com.underdogdevs.springbatch.domain.Section"
    scope="prototype">
</bean>

<bean id="propertyLineTokenizer"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
    <property name="delimiter" value="="></property>
    <property name="names" value="key,value"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="propertyFieldSetMapper"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper">
    <property name="prototypeBeanName" value="property"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="property" class="com.underdogdevs.springbatch.domain.Property"
    scope="prototype">
</bean>
```

You see that I also used a custom `LineTozenizer`. I probably could've just used a `DelimitedLineTokenizer`, but by the time I realized it, I had already defined the class

```
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DefaultFieldSetFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.FieldSet;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.FieldSetFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.LineTokenizer;

public class SectionLineTokenizer implements LineTokenizer {

    private final String nameField = "name";
    private final FieldSetFactory fieldSetFactory = new DefaultFieldSetFactory();

    @Override
    public FieldSet tokenize(String line) {
        String name = line.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "").trim();

        return fieldSetFactory.create(new String[] { name },
                new String[] { nameField });
    }
}
```

Using the following writer and job

```
<bean id="outputFile"
    class="org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource" scope="step">
    <constructor-arg value="#{jobParameters[outputFile]}"></constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="outputFileWriter"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter">
    <property name="resource" ref="outputFile"></property>
    <property name="lineAggregator">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.PassThroughLineAggregator">
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<batch:step id="outputStep">
    <batch:tasklet>
        <batch:chunk commit-interval="10" reader="sectionFileReader"
            writer="outputFileWriter">
        <batch:streams>
            <batch:stream ref="sectionFileReader" />
            <batch:stream ref="trueSectionFileReader" />
        </batch:streams>
        </batch:chunk>
    </batch:tasklet>
</batch:step>

<batch:job id="iniJob">
    <batch:step id="step1" parent="outputStep"></batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

And using this ini file

```
[Cat]
a=1
b=2
c=3
d=4
e=5
f=6
[Cat2]
a=11
b=21
c=31
d=41
e=51
f=61
```

I get the following output, which is the format in my `toString()` of the `Section` class

```
Cat,a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4,e=5,f=6
Cat2,a=11,b=21,c=31,d=41,e=51,f=61
```

Comment: I'm very thankful I'll look into it .. I'm new to spring batch when I was checking the official documentation I was confused they don't give a clear view to implement your own batch ..

Comment: Hope it worked out for you. Let me know if you have any questions about it.