# Record splitting and grouping in spring batch

Tags: split, javabeans, grouping, record, spring-batch

I have a requirement to split my input file which contains records of different length and type some beans. I am able to map each record to different bean using CompositeItemReader. But there is some parent-child relation exists between these records. I want to form a bean which contains child beans. Any help is appreciated.

This is my sample input file.

AB,01,05,HHGFG,05
CD,452,63,FDD,07,54,76,EQWED 
PT,GGG,76,YYY 
CD,08,06,ASW,97,55,66,BT 
AB,96,87,KKK,03 
PT,TIPWQ,19,YEQ 
PT,ROPRG,39,PRVM

### CD,08,06,ASW,97,55,66,BT

Here AB is considered as parent record. My segments start with AB*, CD*, PT*

Comment: Do all the child beans/lines come directly after the parent (in the file)? For instance ParentLine1->childLine->childLine->ParentLine2->childLine->childLine

Comment: This is my sample input file AB,01,05,HHGFG,05
CD,452,63,FDD,07,54,76,EQWED
PT,GGG,76,YYY
CD,08,06,ASW,97,55,66,BT
AB,96,87,KKK,03
PT,TIPWQ,19,YEQ
PT,ROPRG,39,PRVM
CD,08,06,ASW,97,55,66,BT

Comment: AB,01,05,HHGFG,05
CD,452,63,FDD,07,54,76,EQWED
PT,GGG,76,YYY
CD,08,06,ASW,97,55,66,BT
AB,96,87,KKK,03
PT,TIPWQ,19,YEQ
PT,ROPRG,39,PRVM
CD,08,06,ASW,97,55,66,BT

Comment: That doesn't really say much without explaining the relation. You should also just edit your post with new information, instead of writing it in the comments. That way you can format it with some markdown. Also please answer the question in my first comment.

Comment: Hello, Do you have any excample for AggregateItemReader.?

Comment: `AggregateItemReader` is custom class created for that example linked by @LucaBassoRicci in his answer. Look in the src/main/resources/job of the project and look for the multilineOrder job. There's you will see a use.

Comment: Have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24246311/2587435) that uses a similar approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Top level domain object creation is responsability of `ItemReader` so this type of aggregation should be done in reading phase.
In [SB-sample-projects](https://github.com/langmi/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-samples/) there is a [multilineOrder](https://github.com/langmi/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/sample/domain/multiline) sample where you have a skeleton about how to resolve this type of problem; of course you have to resolve "manually" parent/child relationship between objects and manage errors during read.
Another example at [Spring Batch :Aggregated reader / writer Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303106/spring-batch-aggregated-reader-writer-issue)

Comment: Hi Luca, If possible can you provide some examples for AggregatedItemReader? I dont find any.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/sample/domain/multiline/AggregateItemReader.java
also check linked question to my answer